# OPENPYXL populate new worksheets

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a series of 10 pandas dataframes each with 100 rows and 6 columns. I am trying to use openpyxl to write the data into an xlsx. Each dataframe should be in a separate worksheet of the workbook. The sheets are being created, however, all of the results are being entered on the first sheet only (so I get 10 sheets, 9 empty and one with 1000 rows- when I should have 10 sheets with 100 rows each). How can I fix this?

Here is the code for the first 2 sheets:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Create the hospital_ranking workbook
hospital_ranking = Workbook()
dest_filename1 = "hospital_ranking.xlsx"

ws1 = hospital_ranking.active
ws1.title = "Nationwide"

from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

# Write the nationwide query to ws1
for r in dataframe_to_rows(national_results, index = False, header = True):
    ws1.append(r)

for cell in ws1['A'] + ws1[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'

# Create the worksheet for each focus state

# CA
ws2 = hospital_ranking.create_sheet(title = 'California')
ws2 = hospital_ranking.active


# Write the CA query to ws2
for r in dataframe_to_rows(ca_results, index = False, header = True):
    ws2.append(r)

for cell in ws2['A'] + ws2[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'

hospital_ranking.save(filename = os.path.join("staging/") + dest_filename1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after you created the sheet, you need to refer to it :
Don't rebind `ws2` to the workbook's active sheet.

```
ws2 = hospital_ranking.active
```

Is the same as:

```
ws2 = ws1
```

Comment: 'code' ws2 = hospital_ranking.create_sheet(title = 'California')
ws2 = hospital_ranking.get_sheet_by_name('California')
ws2 = hospital_ranking.active 'code' still produces the same result

Comment: @zsad512 -- just remove `ws2 = hospital_ranking.active ` it's pointing to the active sheet (the first)

Answer (score 2):

You are overly complicating things and don't need most (if not all) of the code you posted. Simply use [df.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) which accepts a `sheet_name` argument.

```
import pandas as pd

ew = pd.ExcelWriter('excel.xlsx')

list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
list_of_worksheet_names = [sheet1, sheet2, sheet3]
for df, sheet_name in zip(list_of_dfs, list_of_worksheet_names):
    df.to_excel(ew, sheet_name=sheet_name)

ew.save()
```

Comment: how would I write the resulting spreadsheet to the "staging" directory?

Comment: and how can i ignore the index?

Comment: I would accept this as the answer if I could get those two questions answered, as they are absolutely essential to my task and the long way accomplishes them

Comment: Using openpyxl's utility gives users considerably more control especially when working with existing workbooks.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way might be to us df.to_excel

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using openpyxl as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlfile, engine='openpyxl')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='California')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Arizona')
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Texas')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```